# Difference between Array and List initialization in Scala

Tags: scala

In terms of `Array`, when no initial values are given, `new` is required, along with an explicit type:

```
val ary = new Array[Int](5)
```

But for `List`:

```
val list1 = List[Int]() // "new" is not needed here.
```

When I add `new`, an error occurs:

```
scala> val list = new List[Int]()
<console>:7: error: class List is abstract; cannot be instantiated
       val list = new List[Int]()
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `new` always means you're calling a constructor.

It seems like there's some confusion about the difference between classes and companion objects.

```
scala> new Array[Int](5)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> Array[Int](5)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(5)
```

In the first expression, `Array` refers to the type, and you're calling a constructor.

The second expression desugars to `Array.apply[Int](5)`, and `Array` refers to the companion object.

You can't write `new List` because, as the error and [the doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) says, `List` is abstract.

When you write `List(5)`, you're calling the `apply` method on [`List`'s companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List$).

```
scala> List[Int](5)
res2: List[Int] = List(5)
```

[`List`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1) doesn't have a constructor you can call because `List` is abstract. `List` is abstract because it's a cons list, so a `List` instance can either be `cons` and `nil` (or, as the Scala library calls them, `::` and `Nil`).

But you can call the `::` constructor if you really want to.

```
scala> new ::('a', new ::('b', Nil))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.::[Char] = List(a, b)
```

Comment: why Array can be initialized by calling a constructor, but List cannot? Why Scala designs something like that?

Comment: There isn't really any other way to design a cons list. I've updated my answer with an attempt to explain.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `List` is abstract, so it can't be instantiated.

Second, you're using the wrong method for `List`. `List.apply` initializes a list with the elements from the parameters. You're looking for `List.fill` (though you're better off initializing its elements at once).